# finding the set of all possible values for z?

Tags: real-analysis

Question: suppose $w,x,y,z$ are real numbers such that $|2-w|\le 4$, $|w-x|\le 5$, $|x-y|\le7$ and $|y-z|\le10$. find the set of all possible values of $z$.

thoughts: am I supposed to have $4$ different possible answers for each variable? or how do I even go about obtaining an answer? I need help.

Comment: Use the fact that $|a - b| = d(a,b)$.

Comment: I need more info. Can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consequently draw the sets for admissible $w,x,y$, and $z$.